# macOS - pf.conf - routing from one interface to another based on user

Tags: ios, macos, networking, routes, filtering

I have multiple interfaces, and want to config how the traffic will go out based on the users, for example:

- I have two users: admin and testuser
- I have two network interfaces: en0 and en1
- I want that all the traffic from admin routing to en0 and all the traffic from testuser routing to en1

I tried to modify `/etc/pf.conf` for testuser as below:

```
pass in route-to { en1 } all user { testuser }
pass out route-to { en1 } all user { testuser }
```

When I login as `testuser` and did `curl`, no response was returned. It seems that it was routed to en1 but the reply was rejected? What did I miss here, what is the right way to achieve this?